# Subgroups of free groups question

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, free-groups

I am just reading Allufi chapter 0. I have a specific question in regards to a comment that the book made.

"By Proposition 6.9, every nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact iso-morphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Putting this a little strangely, it says that every subgroup of the free group on one generator is free."

I am not sure I understand this. Is it saying that subgroup of free groups on one generator is isomorphic to a subgroup of free groups of one generator ? I am guessing I am right in my understanding, because the second comment it is saying beware that free groups on two generators contain subgroups isomorphic to free group of arbitrary generators.

Comment: As a minor note, the restatement is a slightly different claim. First, the restatement only states that the subgroups are free and not that they are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ (which would also be false given the next point). Second, the restatement doesn't restrict to nontrivial subgroups, but that's fine because the trivial (sub)group is also a free group (on zero generators). That said, once you do establish that all subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are free, it is very easy to prove that they must be free groups generated by at most one generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understood it right. The only free group of one generator is $\mathbb{Z}$ up to isomorphism. So its non trivial subgroups are isomorphic to it. With free groups of more than one generator it becomes much more complicated.